# OpenGL glDrawElements has no color

Tags: opengl, rendering

I'm trying to draw a cube with OpenGL using shaders I wrote, I can see the shape but no color.

```
#define EDGE_LENGTH 0.6
enum VertexAttrib
{
    ATTRIB_VERTEX = 0, ATTRIB_COLOR
};
int main()
{
    GLfloat cubeAttribs[] =
    {
        -EDGE_LENGTH / 2,   EDGE_LENGTH / 2,    -EDGE_LENGTH / 2,   // 0 front left top vertex
        1.0f,   0.0f,   0.0f,   // red
        -EDGE_LENGTH / 2,   -EDGE_LENGTH / 2,   -EDGE_LENGTH / 2,   // 1 front left bottom vertex
        1.0f,   1.0f,   0.0f,   // yellow
        EDGE_LENGTH / 2,    -EDGE_LENGTH / 2,   -EDGE_LENGTH / 2,   // 2 front right bottom vertex
        0.0f,   1.0f,   0.0f,   // green
        EDGE_LENGTH / 2,    EDGE_LENGTH / 2,    -EDGE_LENGTH / 2,   // 3 front right top vertex
        0.0f,   0.0f,   1.0f,   // blue
        EDGE_LENGTH / 2,    EDGE_LENGTH / 2,    EDGE_LENGTH / 2,    // 4 back right top vertex
        1.0f,   0.0f,   1.0f,   // purple
        EDGE_LENGTH / 2,    -EDGE_LENGTH / 2,   EDGE_LENGTH / 2,    // 5 back right bottom vertex
        1.0f,   0.5f,   0.2f,   // orange
        -EDGE_LENGTH / 2,   -EDGE_LENGTH / 2,   EDGE_LENGTH / 2,    // 6 back left bottom vertex
        1.0f,   1.0f,   1.0f,   // white
        -EDGE_LENGTH / 2,   EDGE_LENGTH / 2,    EDGE_LENGTH / 2,    // 7 back left top vertex
        0.0f,   1.0f,   1.0f    // cyan
    };
    GLushort cubeIndices[] =
    {
        0, 1, 2, 3, // front face
        3, 2, 5, 4, // right face
        4, 5, 6, 7, // back face
        7, 6, 1, 0, // left face
        0, 3, 4, 7, // top face
        6, 5, 2, 1  // bottom face
    };
/* create window and make GL contex */
    ... ...
/* create shader program and use the program */
    ... ...
    GLuint vertexArrayObject;
    GLuint vertexBufferObject;
    GLuint indexBuffer;

/* create vertex array object and bind to it */
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayObject);
    glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);
/* create vertex buffer object */
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferObject);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
/* enable Attributes */
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_COLOR);
/* send vertex position and color data to graphic card memory */
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cubeAttribs), cubeAttribs, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer( ATTRIB_VERTEX, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                        6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (const GLvoid *)0 );
    glVertexAttribPointer( ATTRIB_COLOR, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                        6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (const GLvoid *) ( 3 * sizeof(GLfloat) ) );

/* create index buffer object */
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
/* send index data to graphic card memory */
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cubeIndices), cubeIndices, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

/* bind to the VAO */
    glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);
    while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose(window) )
    {
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   CHECK_GL_ERROR
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   CHECK_GL_ERROR
    /* draw the cube */
        glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 4 * 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid *)0);  CHECK_GL_ERROR
        glFlush();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The shaders are fairly simple.

vertex shader:

```
#version 440
layout(location = 0) in vec4 vertexPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexColor;
smooth out vec3 vColor;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vertexPos;
    vColor = vertexColor;
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 440
smooth in vec3 vColor;
out vec3 outColor;
void main()
{
    outColor = vColor;
}
```

The program compiles and runs, I see the blue background and a back square, but no color. What did I miss ?

Previously I wrote my "first triangle", it was not index based rendering, which uses glDrawArrays to render, the color appears perfectly. The shaders and program structure is almost the same, I tried to find the difference, but got no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a custom fragment output which you have tell OpenGL about. Without that, if using a compatibility profile it expects the fragment color to be emitted through the special built-in variable `gl_FragColor`. But using a core profile you need to use [glBindFragDataLocation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBindFragDataLocation.xhtml) to associate fragment shader outputs with renderbuffer targets. In most case you have only one render target `0`. So in your case after creating the program object call

```
glBindFragDataLocation(program, 0, "outColor");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This problem was actually caused by my own sillyness. A misspell caused my fragment shader not being linked to the shader program. And I found that it's not necessary to specify fragment data location explicitly. Thank you anyway !!!  :)